# is it possible to use wildcards on context docBase

Tags: tomcat, wildcard, context.xml

Is it possible to use wildcards in the docbase as in example below? If not, Is there a workaround for this?

```
<Context path="/somepath" docBase="name-somewildcards"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

A few notes:

1. Don't put `<Context>` into `server.xml`
2. When you don't have `<Context>` in `server.xml`, the `path` attribute is illegal
3. If you want multiple web applications deployed, create a `context.xml` file for each of them. You can script the creation of these if you wish
4. If you want to deploy all the applications in a particular directory, why not simply set `appBase` for that `<Host>` to be that directory, and everything inside it will auto-deploy?